# Using a Vue plugin in another Vue plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am rebuilding my website using Vue in the frontend and Django Rest Framework in the backend. Since the authentication/headers/error handling for all the AJAX calls is going to be the same I figured I should put that in some shared file. So I created a `fetchPlugin.js` that deals with that and I plugged it into my Vue instance under `$fetch`.

To put up notifications I am using `vue-notification`, with a simple call to `$notify` I can put up notifications anywhere. Except in my `$fetch` plugin. Inside of a callback function of the fetches in my plugin the calls do work when I use it like `Vue.prototype.$notify`. But directly inside of function it does not. See my commented code here:

```js
let fetchPlugin = {}
fetchPlugin.install = function(Vue, options){
    Vue.prototype.$fetch = {

        get(url, processingFunction, show_loading=false, extra_options={}){
            if(show_loading){

                // This call does not work
                Vue.prototype.$notify({
                    group: 'loading',
                    title: 'Loading...',
                    type: 'success'
                })
            }

            let default_options = {
                credentials: 'same-origin',
            }
            options = Object.assign(default_options, extra_options)
            fetch(url, options)
                .then(function(response){
                    if(show_loading){

                        // This call works
                        Vue.prototype.$notify({
                            group: 'loading',
                            clean: true
                        })
                    }
                    if(!response.ok){ throw response }
                    return response.json()
                })
                .then(processingFunction)
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)

                    // This call also works
                    Vue.prototype.$notify({
                        group: 'fetch',
                        title: 'An error occurred',
                        type: 'error'
                    })
                })    
        }
    }
}
export default fetchPlugin
```

In my `main.js` I am importing and using `vue-notification` before my `fetchPlugin`, so I figured I would have access to the `$notify` function that `vue-notification` added. Since during the setup time there is no Vue instance yet to reference:

```js
Vue.use(Notification)
Vue.use(fetchPlugin)
```

But apparently that doesn't quite work as I expected. Why does accessing `$notify` work inside of the `.then` functions but not outside of them? How can I get the loading notification to work?

---

Update: I have verified with `console.log(Vue.prototype)` that `$notify` is present both in the fetch callback function and in the beginning of my plugin's `get` function. Otherwise it would of course also throw some exception in my face. The question is then why no notification will popup if the function is called correctly and no exception happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out with help from the maintainer on Github :-)

I made it so that another call would put up an notification but only when I pressed the button, then the notification did work. So I looked at when I did the first call and that was in the created lifecycle hook of the root element. The notification element doesn't exist at that point in time of course. I changed that function to be called on the mounted lifecycle hook and then everything works great.

https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification/issues/92